# How to change DesktopThresholdWidth in Docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

Right now it seems like the desktop breakpoint is hard-coded to 996 (see [here](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/72990726e56e913f735166e70cb901061e9c648c/packages/docusaurus-theme-classic/src/theme/hooks/useWindowSize.ts#L24)). Is there a way we could override this?